# How to know which Pricebook being chosen for an Order

Tags: pricebook, order

I am planning to write a lightning web component to check which Pricebook is being used.
However my problem is that from the Order, I can trace back to the Contract and from Contract I can have the field **Pricebook2Id** but it has null value even though I did select the first product to associate it with one Pricebook before.

Thus would you please advise from coding how do I know exactly which Pricebook has been chosen for that Order?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: please explain why `Order.Pricebook2Id` can't be used

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. There is no Pricebook2Id field in Order object. However, I discovered if I set it in Contract then I can know which Pricebook that is being used. It's just a little bit of a surprise that if we don't set Pricebook2Id in Contract, then we still can choose the Pricebook for that Order when we click "Add Products'. But my question is at that moment, how do we know which price book is chosen since  the Pricebook2Id field in Contract is still blank? Which object is used to save the Pricebook2Id? I am looking forward to your advice.

Comment: ?? see [SFDC Order Object Ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_order.htm?search_text=order) - there is a Pricebook2Id for Order

Comment: Hi cropredy, Thanks a lot for the reference page. I can use the Order.Pricebook2Id now :)! I used to use the Object Manager in Setup to see which fields exists in the Order object and I did not see Pricebook2Id there but this field really exists in the Order object. How fool I am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Order object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_order.htm?search_text=order) includes a field `Pricebook2Id` which should be usable by you.

This field exists because the Order's `OrderItems` point at `PricebookEntry` (PBE) records and Salesforce enforces that all PBE must have the same `Pricebook` as the parent `Order` (same rule as for `Opportunities/OpportunityLineItems`; `Quote/QuoteItems`)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy